# Row_number & Partition By in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I am stuck with the row number over one column group by another column.

This is my data set

```
PR_Cmd      PR_Expd
--------------------------
CVP909104   LVP1ET03904305      
CVP909105   LVP1ET03904306      
CVP909105   LVP1ET03904306      
CVP909105   LVP1ET03904306      
CVP909105   LVP1ET03904306      
CVP909105   LVP1ET03904306      
CVP909105   LVP1ET03904307      
CVP909106   LVP1ET03904308
```

What I want to get :

```
PR_Cmd      PR_Expd             Expd_Number
-------------------------------------------
CVP909104   LVP1ET03904305      1
CVP909105   LVP1ET03904306      1
CVP909105   LVP1ET03904306      1
CVP909105   LVP1ET03904306      2
CVP909105   LVP1ET03904307      3
CVP909106   LVP1ET03904308      1
```

Comment: The logic for `expd_number` eludes me.  What happened to the rest of the rows?  What are `PK_Order` and `PK_Shipment`?

Comment: sorry PK_Order and PK_Shipment are the same PR_Cmd and Pr_Expd

Comment: Ok, but you haven't explained the logic behind why each row has the number it does. Is it simply every 3 rows increment the number by 1?

Comment: An Order (PK_Cmd) have multiple Shipment (PK_Expd), what i want to do, is to have the number of shipment by an order using row_number.

Comment: What is the logic...?

Comment: But a simple `ROW_NUMBER` would return the numbers 1,2,3,4,5... Not 1,1,1,2,2,2... The users here aren't mind readers, you need to explain.

Comment: yes, it's where i'm stucking i don't know how to use row_number and over (partition ..) to get such a result.

Comment: The exemple i used is not clear, but what i want to have is that the row_number restart at 1 every distinct PK_Cmd, and change value every distinct PK_Expd

Comment: i edited the data set it should be easy to understand now

Comment: It's not *easy to understand*, how do you assign the values to rows 4-6? And why do you get less rows in your result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to want is `dense_rank()`.

```
dense_rank() over (partition by pr_cmd order by pr_expd)
```

This will restart the numbering for each value of `pr_cmd`.

Comment: No but the row_number have to restart at 1 every distinct PR_Cmd,

Comment: @MohammedElMehdiKherrachi . . . Then you want `partition by`.  See the revised version.